# Filtering Email Attachments based on Email Id in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-online, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use the Logic App 'List Records' connector for CRM Online to move attachments to SharePoint Online, For example- when an email is created with an attachment in CRM, I am trying to move the attachment to SharePoint Online.  I am successful in moving all the attachments from all the emails in the system in one go but I want to filter the attachments based on single email as similar to how we do in C# plugin/workflow by querying the entity "activitymimeattachment". But I couldn't achieve it through filtering in Logic Apps(I have tried entering filter as "_objectid_value eq EMAILMESSAGE") AND also from the given list of entities, or by entering a custom value of the entity as "activitymimeattachment" which is not exposed. My Logic App is Failing . If this entity is not exposed, how can we can get the attachment list for an email?

Please give some suggestions on it...Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger on the creation of attachment event. I am doing this way because using a function I can get the GUID of email.

Microsoft has only exposed attachmentid field.

I was trying to trigger LA on create of Attachment, However logic App was not triggering, even when I was testing it after adding a file on email entity. I think this a bug.

Comment: I edited the post to make it look like an answer. Henceforth, please do not phrase your answer in such a way that it looks like it's asking clarification from the user. Take care the next time, regards.